# Are the following functions positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there a quick way of determining whether the following functions are positive-definite or not?

$f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$

- $f(x) = 3$
- $f(x) = -3$
- $f(x) = x - 3$
- $f(x) = x + 3$

So, my attempts:

For $f(x) = x - 3$ if we take $n=1, a_1 = 1$ and $x_1$ arbitrary then $$1 \cdot f(x_1 - x_1) \cdot \overline{1} = 1 \cdot f(0) \cdot \overline{1} = 1 \cdot -3 \cdot \overline{1} = -3 < 0$$ so it is not.

Similar reasoning can be made on $f(x) = -3$. Is this part correct so far?

Now, $f(x) = 3$ seems to be positive definite but on the other hand if I take $a_1 = 1, a_2 = -1$ and arbitrary $x_1, x_2$ then
$$a_1 f(x_1 - x_1) \overline{a_1} + a_1 f(x_1 - x_2) \overline{a_2} + a_2 f(x_2 - x_1) \overline{a_1} + a_2 f(x_2 - x_2) \overline{a_2} = \\
= 3 ( 1 \cdot \overline{1} + 1 \cdot \overline{-1} -1 \cdot \overline{1} -1 \cdot \overline{-1}) = 3 ( 1 - 1 - 1 + 1 ) = 0 $$ and it is not greater than zero! Does that mean the function is not positive definite?

What about $f(x) = x + 3$? Here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @badatmath An edit was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real $x_i$'s we have $$\sum \sum a_ia_j ((x_i+3)-(x_j+3))$$ $$=\sum \sum a_ia_j (x_i-x_j)$$ $$= (\sum a_j) (\sum a_ix_i) -(\sum a_i) (\sum a_jx_j) =0$$ so $f$ is  certainly not positive definite.

Comment: Thank you. What about $f(x) = 3$. Is my answer correct?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев Yes, it is correct.

Comment: what if we wanted to check if it is positive semi-definite? (we allow = 0)

Comment: I glanced over to [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function) and one of the necessary conditions there is that $|f(x)| \leq f(0)$. For $f(x)=x+3$ we have $4 = |f(1)| \geq f(0) = 3$. Wouldn't that make the function not semi-definite or am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев You are right. To show that $x+3$ is not positive definite I have used real scalars. But to show that it is non-negative definite we have to use complex scalars and my computation fails there.  $x+3$ is not non-negative definite.